# Is it ok to store any Core Foundation type in NSMutableDictionary by casting it to id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation, foundation

Is there any risk in storing any Core Foundation type in NSMutableDictionary by simple casting it to id?

Answer (score 0):

As CoreFoundation objects are not compatible with ARC, you need to do its release and autorelease yourself. Also you need to bridge cast it by using these, as simply casting to `id` may lead to some problem:

__bridge

__bridge_transfer

__bridge_retained

Answer (score 0):

NS collection types are used to contains objC objects, CF types aren't objC objects. What you can do is use [toll free bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) and [ARC bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) where you can, but not all CF types have a corresponding class in Foundation. 
I never tried but I think that you can save just the pointer of a CF object inside an [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and later add it to a collection, but be aware about memory management.

Comment: However, even something like CFBundleRef can be stored in an NSArray or NSDictionary if you do it right; you just must be aware that casting it to NSBundle* will get you into trouble.

Comment: I was able to cast a CF object that has no corresponding class in Foundation to id type and save it in the dictionary fine.  Is there any danger to this?

Comment: Yes.. if you try to filter that dictionary with a predicate, I'm pretty sure it will crash, also send some KVC key path. The only way I see is to wrap it in a NSValue, if it is bridged is fine. About which CF type are we talking about?